# bash get only the highest (folder hierarchy wise) location result into a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to get only the highest (folder hierarchy wise) location result into a variable using bash.

```
administrator@JenkisSrv01:/tmp/test/frontend-2.0$ find -name pom.xml
./server/pom.xml
./server/mock/pom.xml
./assembly/pom.xml
./pom.xml
```

I want only the location of the parent folder of the pom.xml to insert into a variable.

**LOCATION=./** or absolute path can also work using "pwd" **LOCATION=/tmp/test/frontend-2.0**

I can't think of a good command to get this info into a variable...
anyone?

Comment: There can obviously be more than one file with the smallest number of subdirectories if there is no matching file in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the directory names you can use command like

```
find $(pwd) -name pom.xml -exec dirname {} \;
```

If you want to get only the shortest path you can run something like:

```
find $(pwd) -name pom.xml -exec dirname {} \; | awk '{ print length($0) " " $0; }' | sort -r -n|cut -d ' ' -f 2-|tail -1
```

Comment: Piping does not make sense when you have multiple results on find.

Comment: I suggest, give the example in the question, instead of `/path` use `$(pwd)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what I meant is that I need to get only the highest (folder hierarchy wise) location, in this case: /tmp/test/mGrid-frontend-2.0  .While ignoring the others

Comment: I don't think that `length` is a reliable way to go.  For example, ./assembly/pom.xml
./server/mock/pom.xml
./server/pom.xml
./a/b/c/pom.xml gives /home/user/a/b/c/ as the shortest.

Answer (score 1):

This will collect the path(s) with the lowest number of slashes, and print them out into the command substitution.

```
location=$(find . -name pom.xml -exec dirname {} \; |
    awk -F / 'NR==1 || NF < min { min=NF; i=0 }
        NF<=min { a[++i] = $0 }
        END { for(j=1; j<=i; ++j) print a[j] }')
```

`NF` is the number of fields (so because of `-F /` also the number of slashes, plus one) and `NR` is the current line number. So collect the paths with the smallest number of slashes into the array `a`, and if we see a new smallest number, start over. (The order of these conditions is reversed in the script, to avoid repeating things.) At the end, print the accumulated array of path names.

If your file names are not completely regular, probably collect them into a Bash array instead of a string.

Don't use upper case for your private variables; uppercase variables are reserved for system use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an escape character (\0x1b) is not included in the filenames, how about:

```
esc=$'\e'
while read -r -d "" f; do
    printf "%s%c" "${f//[^\/]/}$esc$f" $'\0'
done < <(find . -name pom.xml -print0) | sort -t "$esc" -z -k 1 | head -1 -z | cut -d "$esc" -z -f 2
```

yields:

```
./pom.xml
```

At first it extracts slashes from the filenames, append the slashes to the original filenames with an escape as a delimiter, then sort, head, and cut out the filename. The count of slashes are used to sort out the least-slashed file.

Comment: It's nice to use -print0 and `esc` in an effort to be conscious of special characters in filenames, but that breaks on `sort`, `head`, and `cut`, which will not handle files with a newline in the name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've updated my answer to support filenames which contain newline characters. Note that older version of `sort`, `head`, and `cut` may not support `-z` option.

Comment: This will still break if the filename contains a backslash code which gets interpreted by `echo -e`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU find lets you -printf `%d` to list a file's depth in the dir tree, and `%h` to list the leading dirs of its name, cf. `info '(find) Format Directives'`.

The target file being pom.xml I'd expect the following to do what you want: ascending sort on depth, and return dirname from first line. The `realpath` step can be skipped if `$root` is absolute. Requires filenames without tabs or newlines.

```bash
v=$(find "${root:-${PWD}}" -type f -name pom.xml -printf '%d\t%h\n' | sort -n | head -n1 | cut -f2)
v=$(realpath -e "$v")
```